# Correct MySQL syntax for the SUM of multiple COLUMNS where multiple WHERE exists?

Tags: mysql

I have the following database table:

`+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| results_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| community_id   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_name   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_team   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_goals  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_result | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_goals  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_result | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_name   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_team   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_pts    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_pts    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date           | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

I want to run a MySQL query that will tell me who a player has scored the most goals against.

That player can either be player1 or player2.

I imagine it being something like this:

```
select member, goals, count(*) Total
from 
(
select player2_name as member, player1_goals as goals
from results
WHERE player1_id = 2
union all
select player1_name as member, player2_goals as goals
from results
WHERE player2_id = 2 

) AS T

group by goals
order by Total desc
Limit 1
```

This gives a result:

```
member        | goals | Total
Jamie Charles | 2     | 11
Jamie Charles | 0     |  8
Jamie Charles | 3     |  5
Jamie Charles | 1     |  4
Jamie Charles | 5     |  1
```

But it looks like it is saying how many of that number of goals has occurred.  So the correct result would be `(2x11)+(3*5)+(1*4)+(5*1)`

What is the correct Syntax for this query?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT (SELECT SUM(player1_goals) FROM results WHERE player1_id = 2) + (SELECT SUM(player2_goals) FROM results WHERE player2_id = 2)`?

Comment: just tried that, didn't work

Comment: What errors do you actually get?

Comment: sorry, i've updated the question - I had only provided half of what I was trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by member, use the `sum` aggregate function to get the sum of all the goals. You do not need the order

```
select member, sum(goals), count(*) Total_goal_records
from 
(
select player2_name as member, player1_goals as goals
from results
WHERE player1_id = 2
union all
select player1_name as member, player2_goals as goals
from results
WHERE player2_id = 2 

) AS T

group by member 
order by Total desc;
```

Comment: Excellent! That did it! Thanks!